# Resolve domain names in QEMU VDE setup

Tags: virtualization, dns, dnsmasq

I have re-built QEMU with VDE support. For the uninitiated, VDE attaches a virtual switch program (vde_switch) to a TAP device which allows multiple VDE-enabled programs to utilize a single TAP device.

My ultimate goal here is to be able to resolve my virtual machines by hostname such as "test1.qemu" "machineb.qemu", etc from my host -- this will ease configuration for me in many circumstances since I use DHCP via dnsmasq on the TAP interfaces.

Really this is probably a matter of not fully understanding how name resolution works, so I'm hoping to learn something out of this =)

Firstly, my dnsmasq configuration file:

```
user=nobody
interface=tap0
except-interface=lo
listen-address=192.168.1.1
#Assign IP's 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.253 for 8 hrs
dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.253,255.255.255.0,192.168.1.255,8h
pid-file=/var/run/dnsmasq_tap0.pid
dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.vde.leases
domain=qemu
server=/qemu/
#Only really run on tap0, needed so there is no confliction with
#NetworkManager's dnsmasq
bind-interfaces
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-no-override
strict-order
```

As you can see, I have configured dnsmasq to answer for "*.qemu" names. I can ping 192.168.1.1 properly, but as is stands, 'ping qemu' doesn't work. I assumed this was because my host machine didn't know how to resolve 'qemu', so I added it to the /etc/hosts file. Though, I'm not sure this is the proper way to do this. Of course, after adding the entry to /etc/hosts, qemu resolves but not i386.qemu (one of my VM's).

I guess a good starting point would be: how do I tell my machine to forward all *.qemu requests to the dnsmasq running on 192.168.1.1 (local interface tap0)?

Also, if it's any help, here is my /etc/network/interfaces entry for tap0:

```
auto tap0
iface tap0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    vde2-switch -
    pre-up /sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    pre-up /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
    up /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -C /etc/dnsmasq.d/vde-network --pid-file=/var/run/dnsmasq_tap0.pid --bind-interfaces
    post-down /bin/bash -c "kill -9 $(cat /var/run/dnsmasq_tap0.pid)"
    post-down /sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
    post-down /sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I figured out the answer, and it was a bit of a facepalm moment.

I had a file called `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/qemu` which contained an incorrect DNS IP for my qemu dnsmasq instance (192.168.100.1 rather than 192.168.1.1). So, I think what was happening was that when I queried `qemu`, the default NetworkManager instance of netmask attempted to pass the query to 192.168.100.1 which didn't work for obvious reasons.

Once I changed the address to 192.168.1.1 in the config file and restarted NetworkManager (and thus its instance of dnamasq), everything works great! The `/etc/hosts` entry was not required as I had thought.

Now I just have to figure out how to resolve my VM host's hostname to my LAN address within my VM's rather than returning 127.0.1.1 which is incorrect from my VMs' perspective.